# C++ alternative for Python dictionary with list of values

Tags: c++, dictionary, maps

I'm trying to implement a search algorithm to solve a maze but I'm having trouble creating a graph in C++. It looks like this in Python(using dictionary) though:

```
Node={}
Node[(6,6)]=[(6,5),(6,7),(5,6),(7,6)] 
Node[(1,3)]=[(1,4),(2,3)]
```

The keys are a TUPLE and the values are a LIST of TUPLES.I looked around for it(ordered maps etc.), but couldn't find a solution that maps the key value pair this way.
Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: convert tuple to  string

Comment: @SmartManoj: I highly doubt that that is needed.

Comment: Like Python dictionaries, I'm sure C++ hashtables / map implementations can handle arbitrary objects as keys and values. Just declare your map to contain a suitable array / list type.

Comment: Associative containers in C++ can use any object as a key for which a comparison overload is defined (and a hash function, in case of unordered containers). Simply define a map, or an unordered map, keyed by a tuple, and containing a list of tuples. You will likely need to implement your own comparison and hash overloads, but it's possible that with elementary types the defaults provided by the C++ library will be sufficient. That would be logically equivalent to your Python data structure.

Comment: Somewhat related: [unordered\_map with pair as key - not compiling](//stackoverflow.com/q/32685540) Might actually be what you need if I got your intention correctly.

Comment: @BaummitAugen your link led me to find out more about pairs which actually led me to map tuples to tuples.Maybe that's what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ makes you think about the data you are going to use more than Python does.  Fortunately for you, your data seems to be very clearly defined.

The dictionary you want can be implemented as a `std::map`

The tuple you want can be implemented as a `std::pair` or `std::tuple`.

```
// Assuming #include <tuple>
// Assuming #include <map>
// Assuming #include <vector>

using KeyType = std::tuple<int,int>;
using ValueType = std::vector<KeyType>;

std::map< KeyType, ValueType > Nodes;

Nodes[{6,6}]={{6,5},{6,7},{5,6},{7,6}}; 
Nodes[{1,3}]={{1,4},{2,3}};
```

Those `using` lines are for readability, and may be changed or removed as you prefer.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I couldn't figure out how to make a list of values of tuples after I came across the make_tuple() function in C++. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @VaibhavSaini it would seem that you have never marked an answer as accepted.  That lets people know that you are no longer asking for help.

Comment: How do I access the map keys and values. The .at(), .find() functions seems to work fine for maps keyed with strings, but when I try the same with my map, it gives me a long & bizzare error...

Comment: @VaibhavSaini this comment section is not the place to ask new questions. Good luck!